# Gvim, MinGW and Powershell making them work the CLI way

Tags: windows-7, mingw, powershell-2.0

Just shifted to windows7. Liking it :).
Is there a way to install MinGW in windows, such that, i can cd to my code directory (which is different from MinGW install directory) and compile my code there.
IF, no then what is the equivalent of $PATH (bourne shell) in windows, and how shall i set it.   Can this trick (setting MinGW in default path of exe) work on windows7.

Any useful wiki's, blogs, forum would be very very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly possible, first thing you have to do is download MinGW (see *(1)* below for some suggestions). Then install it using the installer if you have one or just decompress the files in a directory (i.e.: `D:\Tools\MinGW`).

Now, set the `PATH` variable (Windows systems have it too) to point to the `bin` directory. To do so, go to `Control Panel\System and Security\System` and click in the `Advanced system settings` options in the left panel. There select `Environmental Variables...` and find it in the `System variables` list.

Note that in Windows the separator among the directories placed in the `PATH` variable is a `;` instead of a `:`.

And you're all set, whatever is on a directory on the `PATH` should be accessible from the command line. Instead of using the system-wide `PATH` you may also create a `PATH` user variable, it's up to you.

To access an environmental variable from the command line you use `%`s (i.e.: `echo %PATH%`). Using the command `set` without parameters in a command line should display the current environment variables. You can use it to set the value of one too (i.e.: `set LIBPATH=D:\Code\Libraries`).

*(1). You may download it from several places: [the original MinGW project](http://www.mingw.org/) (which has an installer too), [TDM builds](http://www.tdragon.net/recentgcc/) (also with an installer), [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) (for 64-bit systems, but has toolchains targeting 32-bit too, also binaries for the 4.5 branch of GCC), ...*

Comment: :D thanks man i am happy. do you know about virtualbox too. if yes i have some questions, i couldnot find help anywhere. :D. thanks a lot. added my gvim and gcc now i can code in windows too the way i want.

Comment: I do, but questions regarding VirtualBox and that sort of things (unless it's a VBox coding thing) should go in the SuperUser site (superuser.com). I'll try to answer them :)

Comment: When setting the System and User path, keep in mind that they are concatenated so that your final PATH = SystemPath + UserPath.  So basically any "system" program will be found before any "user" program.